# How to determine if an object is a DateTime in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

The following works fine in c# (assuming `value` is an `object`):

```
if (value is DateTime)
```

What is the equivalent check for VB.NET?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The VB.Net equivalent is

```
If TypeOf(value) Is DateTime Then
```

Answer (score 10):

### C#

```
if (value.GetType() is typeof(DateTime)) {}
```

### VB.NET (so the converters tell me)

```
If value.[GetType]() Is GetType(DateTime) Then
    '...
End If
```

Comment: Close...but not quite; although you did help me arrive upon the solution: If value.GetType() Is GetType(DateTime) Then

Comment: This will fail if value is Nothing

Comment: This doesn't allow for polymorphism, so isn't the strict equivalent of the C# in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
If TypeOf value Is DateTime Then
```